# Cypress .click() action does not work inside modal

Tags: javascript, cypress, bootbox

I have [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) modal triggered when `#mybutton` is clicked:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){

    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn-success'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
        }
    });
});
```

When I test with cypress everything passes right up to the last test. The `click` call does not close the modal.

```
it('Should raise modal and close it', () => {
    cy.visit('myview/');
    cy.get('#mybutton').click();
    cy.get('.modal-title').should('be.visible');     <-- PASSES
    cy.get('.btn-success').click();
    cy.get('.modal-title').should('not.be.visible')  <-- FAILS
});
```

In reality clicking this button does close the modal. I have tried:

```
cy.get('.btn-success').click({force: true});
cy.get('.btn-success').trigger('click', {force: true});
```

Neither work. Am I in some kind of [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)?

Comment: The example isn't reproducible - cannot find a problem with this code.

Comment: Found the answer: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to have an assertion then an action. Here you may want to add `.should()` to check its visibility or enabled for buttons before sending a click to an element.

```js
cy.get('#mybutton').should('be.visible').click();
cy.get('.modal-title').should('be.visible');
cy.get('.btn-success').should('be.visible').click();
cy.get('.modal-title').should('not.be.visible')
```